# How to backtest an indicator to show the profit without adding profit/loss in short positions in TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to backtest an indicator in Tradingview. I write a strategy in pine editor and when I run it I realized that it calculates the profit by summing the profit/loss between "Long entry" and "Long exit", but also between "Short entry" and "Short exit". I agree that there is an opportunity cost between "Short Entry" and "Short Exit" but i dont want to include it into my profit calculation. How can I prevent the "Short Position Profit/Loss" to be included in my calculation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want it to influence your results, then don't go short.

Or, you need to manually calculate your profits and display it in a table.

Comment: I made the calculation in my code and write it to a label

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to remove `strategy.short` from your `strategy.entry` or `strategy.order`, it will depend on how you write your code.

Removing `strategy.short` the backtest will not create short orders.

Comment: But how can i sell the instrument in my strategy? Isnt it like once i buy the instrument, it will be always hold in Long Order during the entire strategy?